# Variables scope in Java

Tags: java

```
class Grade {
public static int f = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int f = 0; f < 2; f++) {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
}
```

How does it happen, that "int f" overrides the static variable f? I thought that static int f is shared by the whole class and why does not the compiler give the error message that this variable is redefined? Why does it not become the duplicate of the static f? I thought that in java the scope blocks inherit the variables of their parent block.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the local `f`, "shadows" the outer-scope `f`. This means that whenever you refer to `f` after defining it locally, it will refer to the local version.

Wikipedia's page on variable shadowing uses a very similar example in Java:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

EDIT: If you need the “outer” `f`, you can access it by its more proper name: `Grade.f`. Similar example without static variables:

```
public class Grade {
  public int f=0;
  public void setF(int f) {
    this.f = f; // setF(5) will set the “outer” f to 5.
  }
}
```

Comment: That wikipedia page should be pretty clear. So there isn't much else besides knowing how (and where) shadowing comes into play.

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev the official source for Java language questions is The Java Language Specification (aka the JLS). For your question see §6.3.1. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Even if the variable is static, scoping tells the compiler that the line

```
System.out.println(f);
```

works with the inner variable rather than the more generic one. It's something to avoid - naming your variables in such way that their names get confusing.